# Contiguous memory storing misunderstanding in.net?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics, memory-management

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379570(v=vs.80).aspx

I know that `Arrays` in `.net` is stored in a **contiguous** fashion. ( in mem)

I also know that `List<..>` is not. ( well...not all list types... see at my 2'nd question)

From here I have 2 qustions

---

1. I know that after 4,8,16... inserted items to a list - the list `reallocate` itself in memory.

   I also know I can send him the `Capacity` in ctor in order to let him know in what size im gonna create him ( to reduce re-allocation).

   The question is **why** ? he Doesn NOT store itself contiguously , so why does he care about re-
   allocating himself ? ( he doesnt have to find free  & contiguous memory cells)
2. why Does List with structs is allocated in contiguous memory, unlike a List of classes ?

Comment: Missed that Oded.. sorry

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`List<T>` does store memory contiguously.  Internally, it uses an array for its storage.  When you reach the capacity, a new array is allocated and the memory is copied.

This is true for `List<T>` instances of classes or structs.  However, when `T` is a reference type (class), you're storing a *contiguous list of references*.  The class instances cannot be contiguous as you can include a list which contains 100 references to *the same instance* of a class.

As such, to address your specific questions:

> The question is why ? he Doesn NOT store itself contiguously , so why does he care about re- allocating himself ?

It *does* store the items contiguously, which is why the reallocation is required.

> why Does List with structs is allocated in contiguous memory, unlike a List of classes?

Both are stored contiguously, but in the second case (classes) you're storing a list of references to a class instance.

Comment: If i crete a list with 1 item. and he doesnt have a contiguous place for the second onw - will he still reallocate himself ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The list will reallocate as soon as you add an item beyond your current capacity.  If you create the list with a capacity of 1, adding a second item will cause a reallocation.  With classes, this isn't horrible, though, since you're only reallocating and copying the object references, not the object instances themselves.

Comment: oh I didnt know that it still store contiguously in memory. thanks :)it always sat at my mind

Comment: Can someone explain why a List<> is required to store its data contiguously?   I understand that it has the requirement of random-access above and beyond a collection, but can't you implement random access without contiguous memory but have multiple blocks?  That way, if I have a list that requires 100 mbs of memory, it could allocate 5MB chunks or something that might be more efficient for the OS.   I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @zumalifeguard There isn't a "requirement" - it's just the decision made for that specific collection.  There are people who've implemented block-style collections for .NET.  Contiguous data does allow for much faster (especially after inlining) reads, at the expense of more expensive creation/additions.  It also provides much better cache coherency for reading once built.

Comment: Reed, would you be willing to point to some of these block-style collections, if possible.

Comment: @zumalifeguard I think C5 has one, but cna't find it right now - http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-persistentvector-1.html is one (though written in F#)

Answer (score 0):

1) all the object *references* are still stored contigously

2) a list och classes still must let the objects be stored like ordinary objects. thay cannot be forced into a contigious array - but the references to them can