# Cache friendliness in C#

Tags: c#, c++, list, caching, vector

I've just seen a very interesting talk by Herb Sutter at the Build Conference 2014, called "Modern C++: What You Need to Know". Here's a link to the video of the talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661

One of the topics of the talk was on how `std::vector` is very cache-friendly, mainly because it ensures that its elements are adjacent in the heap, which has a great impact on spatial locality, or at least that's what I think I've understood; this is the case even for inserting and removing items. Clever use of `std::vector` can bring dramatic performance improvements by exploiting caching.

I'd like to try something like what with C#/.Net, but how to ensure that the objects in my collections are all adjacent in memory?

Any other pointer to resources on cache-friendliness on C# and .Net is also appreciated. :)

Comment: I think using safe C# means that we are reliant on these types of implementation details being taken care of and hope that the framework makes the best of the memory regarding cache performance. I don't see anything in the spec that guarantees that collections store elements contiguously in memory, but I may have missed something. You can always open the memory viewer, drag elements in and look for yourself (so long as you have a hex calculator handy). A simple example is: `byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( "tester" );`, drag into memory viewer you will see elements are contiguous.

Answer (score 17):

For GC-managed languages, you tend to lose that explicit control over where every object is stored in memory. You can control memory access patterns but that becomes a bit futile if you can't control what memory addresses you are accessing. On top of that, every object tends to come with an unavoidable overhead of an indirection and something resembling a virtual pointer (under the hood) to allow dynamic dispatch, reflection, etc. It's the analogical equivalent of having to store pointers (references) to objects and having to work indirectly with them with each object instance also storing the analogical pointer to allow for runtime type information like reflection and what's needed for virtual dispatch.

As a result, even if you store an array of object references contiguously, that's only making the analogical pointers to the objects cache-friendly to access sequentially. The contents of each object could still be scattered in memory, incurring cache misses galore as you load memory regions into cache lines only to use one object's worth of data before that data gets evicted.

It's actually the number one appeal of a language like C++ to me: it lets you still use OOP while controlling where everything is going to be allocated in memory as well as exactly how much memory everything uses and it lets you opt out (actually by default) from the overhead associated with virtual dispatch, RTTI, etc. while still using objects and generics and so forth. Meanwhile the biggest appeal to me personally of languages like C# and Java is what you can get with each object like reflection, which comes with overhead per object, but is a justified cost if your code has plenty of use for it.

**Using plain old data types (`struct` included in C#):**

That said, I've seen very efficient code written in C# and Java on par with C and C++ but the key difference is that they *avoided objects* for the tiny fraction of code that is really performance-critical. For example, I saw an interactive Java raytracer using single-path tracing with very impressive speed given the brute force nature of what it was doing. However, the key difference is that while most of the raytracer was written using nice object-oriented code, for the performance-critical parts (BVH, mesh representation, and triangles stored in the leaves) it avoided objects and just used big arrays of `int[]` and `float[]`. That performance-critical code was pretty "raw", maybe even more "raw" than equally-optimized C++ code (it looked closer to C or Fortran), but it was only necessary for a few key areas of the raytracer.

When you use arrays of plain old data types for the performance-critical areas, you gain the sufficient control over memory to make all the difference, because it doesn't matter so much if the array is GC-managed and maybe occasionally moved from one memory location to another after a GC cycle (ex: out of Eden space after a first GC cycle). It doesn't matter because the array is moved as a *whole*. As a result the element at index 1 is still right next to elements 0 and elements 2. That's all that matters for cache-friendly sequential processing of an array is that each element in the array is right next to the other in memory, and even in Java and C#, as long as you're using arrays of PODs (which include `structs` in C# the last time I checked), you have that level of control.

So when you're writing performance-critical code, make sure your designs leave enough breathing room to change the representation of how things are stored, and possibly away from objects if the design becomes bottlenecky in the future. As a basic example, for an `Image` object (which is effectively a collection of pixels), you might avoid storing pixels as individual objects and you definitely don't want to expose an abstract `Pixel` object for clients to use directly. Instead you might represent a collection of pixels as an array of plain old integers or floats behind an `Image` interface, and a single image might represent a million pixels. That will allow cache-friendly sequential processing of the image.

**Avoid using `new` for a boatload of teeny things.**

Don't use `new` excessively for teeny things to put it simply. Allocate in bulk for performance-critical areas: one `new` for an entire array of a million integers representing a million pixels in an image, e.g., not a million calls to `new` to allocate one pixel at a time to locations in memory outside of your control. Besides cache-friendliness, if you allocate each pixel as a separate object in C#, the memory overhead required to store the analogical pointer for dynamic dispatch and reflection and so forth will often be bigger than the entire pixel itself, doubling or tripling the memory use of a single pixel.

**Design for bulk, homogeneous processing in performance-critical areas.**

If you're writing a video game revolving around OOP and inheritance rather than ECS and duck typing, the classic inheritance example is often too granular: `Dog` inherits `Mammal`, `Cat` inherits `Mammal`. Instead if you are going to be dealing with a boatload of mammals in your game loops every frame, I recommend instead to make `Cats` inherit `Mammals`, `Dogs` inherit `Mammals`. `Mammals` becomes an abstract container rather than something that just represents one mammal at a time. This will give your designs enough breathing room to process, say, many dogs worth of contiguous primitive data at one time very efficiently when you are trying to process an abstract `Dogs` which inherits abstract `Mammals` when you try to do things indirectly to dogs with polymorphism through the `Mammals` interface.

This advice actually applies regardless of whether you're using C or C++ or Java or C# or anything else. To write cache-friendly code, you have to start with designs that leave enough *breathing room* to optimize their data representations and access patterns as needed in the future, and ideally with a profiler in hand. The worst-case scenario is to end up with a *design* that has accumulated many dependencies which is bottlenecky, like many dependencies to a `Pixel` object or `IPixel` interface, which is too granular to optimize further without rewriting and redesigning the entire software. So avoid mass dependencies to overly granular designs that leave no breathing room to optimize further. Redirect the dependencies away from the analogical `Pixel` to the analogical `Image`, from the analogical `Mammal` to the analogical `Mammals`, and you'll be able to optimize to your heart's content without costly redesigns.

Comment: You've mentioned duck typing. Is there any other way of using duck typing in C# beside using dynamic type which will degrade performance?

Comment: @VladRadu If you have anything which incurs a heavy runtime cost, then see if you can make it a collection of things which only incur that cost once per collection. Very quickly the cost becomes trivial, like doing it once per 64 elements reduces it down to 1/64 the original cost. That's a very generic answer but hopefully, it will do as I'm no C# expert. But OOP wants to make model teeny scalar-type things and for performance-critical stuff, I recommend to model things as big collection-type things.

Comment: @VladRadu A very basic example is with images. Let's say you want to apply image filter to image. If you check every single pixel in some way that incurs runtimes costs like its pixel format, then it will pay a heavy runtime penalty. But if you check it for the entire image one time, no problem. The classical duck typing case is too granular for hotpaths -- "if it has wings, it can fly." Change it to checking in bulk: "if *they* have wings, *they* can fly."

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the only way to achieve this in C# is to use value types, that means using structs instead of classes. Using List will then store your objects in contiguous memory. You can read some more info on structs vs classes here: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use List, which stores items contiguously (like a std::vector).
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183937/1715829) for more info.

Comment: `List` stores the references contiguously for reference types, not the objects themselves. What I'd like to know is if it's possible to force these objects to be adjacent in memory.